# Unable to get the data from Google Plus API

Tags: java, google-plus

I am using the following code to get the Google Plus posts,

```
public class Test { 

 /** E-mail address of the service account. */ 
 private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "4353545    gggggggggg.apps.googleusercontent.com"; 
/** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */ 
private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport(); 
/** Global instance of the JSON factory. */ 
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory(); 
private static Plus plus; 
public static void main(String[] args) { 
  try { 
    try { 
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder() 
          .setClientSecrets("4353545gggggggggg.apps.googleusercontent.com", 
      "gdfgfgdfgdfgdfgdfggf") 
     .build(); 
  plus = new Plus.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT,JSON_FACTORY,credential).build(); 
     getActivity(); 
            // success! 
            return; 

    /** Get an activity for which we already know the ID. */ 
    private static void getActivity() throws IOException { 
    String activityId = "z12stbfxcpmkuthac04ci3gjvoywglkwx0k"; 
    Activity activity = plus.activities().get(activityId).execute(); 

 System.out.println("id: " + activity.getId()); 
 System.out.println("url: " + activity.getUrl()); 
 System.out.println("content: " + 
 activity.getObject().getContent()); 
 } 
 }
```

While running this code  I am getting  the following error,

```
403 Forbidden 
{ 
  "code" : 403, 
  "errors" : [ { 
    "domain" : "usageLimits", 
    "message" : "Daily Limit Exceeded. Please sign up", 
    "reason" : "dailyLimitExceededUnreg", 
    "extendedHelp" : "https://code.google.com/apis/console" 
  } ], 
  "message" : "Daily Limit Exceeded. Please sign up" 
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed getting JSON response, but it seems because you exceeded your number of tries, API not returning any thing. Might be you have test account with limited tries for a day etc.,

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how often you tried, but going off the extendedHelp URL, I checked and saw that Google allows 10,000 visitors daily. Did you perhaps go over the 10,000 visitors, or views?

> Courtesy limit: 10,000 requests/day

Comment: I haven't get even a single data from Google